# why do most banking sites provide 1 plaintext input and 1 secured input for same field on the same page?

Tags: forms, gui-design, input-fields

In multiple banking and finance sites, I have seen form similar to following:

[image]

What is the point of providing 2 kinds of inputs for the same field? I understand that the second field is tied to **confirm** functionality, but my question is since they both are going to contain the same info eventually why do they keep first field as protected and second field as plain-text?

Is it an example of bad design or is it done purposefully? Since this practice is followed by multiple banking / finance websites especially in India, I am curious about the intention.

Comment: Looks like bad coding to me - the input field has been set incorrectly in one of the fields - either they're both meant to be secure of neither

Answer (score 1):

When a user is entering a password or some other masked input, it is common practice to have them enter it again in a second **masked** input box. This is to verify that the user entered what they thought they did, since they cannot visually verify the masked input.

I do not see the sense of having one masked input, and then a second unmasked one where you have to type the same information. If the field needs to be masked for security reasons then both text boxes should have the input masked, otherwise you can have a single text box and let the user verify the information visually.

Answer (score 1):

I would explain it as follows:

1. The developer thinks that a masked field is more securely send to the server
2. The designer thinks that a masked field is bad for the user experience and needs visible verification
3. The verification and masked fields are compared and validated with javascript
4. Once the form gets through the javascript validation, it is posted without the verification field
5. Developers for other banks copy this idea as they think it is good practice

This would all make sense if #1 was true, but it isn't.

Comment: So basically some bigshot might have used this strategy and others followed the same path thinking it to be a standard solution.

Comment: Well, I have no other explanation, but for those banks and their customers I hope there is a better one.